# Facebook Ads API: adaccounts field is deprecated for versions v2.11 and higher

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to fetch all ads accounts through Facebook Ads SDK. I kam getting the following error 
[image]

Here is my code.

```
public function getAdAccounts() {
        $user = new AdAccountUser('**************');
        $user->read(array(AdAccountUserFields::ID));

        $accounts = $user->getAdAccounts();

        // Print out the accounts
        echo "Accounts:\n";
        foreach($accounts as $account) {
          echo $account->id . ' - ' .$account->name."\n";
        }

        // Grab the first account for next steps (you should probably choose one)
        $account = (count($accounts)) ? $accounts->getObjects()[0] : null;
        echo "\nUsing this account: ";
        echo $account->id."\n";
    }
```

I tried it through [explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dadaccounts&version=v3.2&classic=0) and it works.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [User class](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/master/src/FacebookAds/Object/User.php), as example:

```
use FacebookAds\Object\User;

....

$fields = [
    'name',
];

$user = new User($id);

$accounts = $user->getAdAccounts($fields);

// Print out the accounts
echo "Accounts:\n";
foreach($accounts as $account) {
    echo $account->id . ' - ' .$account->name."\n";
}
```

You can also take a look at the [example here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/master/examples/UserAccountsEdge.php).

Comment: Before `AdAccountUser` I tried the `AdUser` class but this class does not exist in the SDK. So I tried the `AdAccountUser`. Any idea?

Comment: You are right! The Class is deprecated/Removed but the doc is not aligned (The example also...)

Comment: Yes, In documentation this method is still there. Don't know what is the new way to get this.

Comment: yes, I just saw your solution, But I already implemented this in the same way. :)

Comment: can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53589105/facebook-ads-api-object-with-id-does-not-exist-cannot-be

Comment: yes @ManojKumar see if my answer works for you (is not needed but a +1 is always appreciated :) )