# Facebook ads API : Object with ID '*****************' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am working on the facebook ads API (3.2) But I am getting some weird errors. I am trying to get the `campaigns` And following is the method I am using for this according to the documentation [Here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk#cursors)

```
public function getcampaigns() {
   $adaccount = new AdAccount('331*****10774');
   $campaigns = $adaccount->getCampaigns();
   print_r($campaigns);
}
```

But I am getting the error 
[image]

Then I try this with [Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) with the same `access_token` and it worked well. 
[image]

I am giving the following permissions in `access_token`

```
$this->permissions = ['email', 'ads_management', 'pages_show_list', 'publish_pages', 'manage_pages', 'ads_read', 'business_management'];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should prefix with the `act_` string, so

try this:

```
   $adaccount = new AdAccount('act_331*****10774');
```

instead of this:

```
   $adaccount = new AdAccount('331*****10774');
```

In addition, if you test the [example](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/master/examples/AdAccountCampaignsEdge.php):

```
use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;

$id = 'act_XXXX';

$api = Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
$api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());

$fields = array(
  'name',
  'objective',
);
$params = array(
  'effective_status' => array('ACTIVE','PAUSED'),
);
echo json_encode((new AdAccount($id))->getCampaigns(
  $fields,
  $params
)->getResponse()->getContent(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Works as expected

Hope this help

Comment: no that's not working because if I pass the id it internally adds the `ACT_` with the id and accepts only integer or a long integer in the param.

Comment: Sorry @ManojKumar but i tested the code and works as expected

Comment: You are a genius, I tried that with `ACT_` but its working with `act_`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your APP approved by Facebook to access the permission [ads_management](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-ads_management)

It will work on explorer since it's just a tool FB has provided to test and play around.

Comment: I can still use the API with development access to read the stuff. No ?

Comment: because I am able to fetch my other account information like adAccounts, campaigns etc.